# Returning HTML in MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

We are building a lot of applications for one business solution. I need to embed a feature of another application into my application. For example, Accounting needs to have the "Customer Management" feature of the Customer Manager, so I just make call to Customer Manager application to retrieve this feature in HTML and display inside my application.

All of them are written in ASP.NET MVC (C#).

Could you please give me some advice to solve this technical problem?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many solutions, depending on your exact needs. Some of them:

**If the HTML is from another web app:**
Use javascript to make a ajax call to an action of this another webapp and insert the response (should be a PartialView) in one DOM element. Look at [jquery.get](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) as an example.

**If the HTML is from your web app**
You can include the HTML when the view is rendered by using `@Html.Partial` or `@Html.Action`. The first includes a partial view in your view, the second includes the response of a controller's action of your application in the view.
Another option is to pass the HTML as a property of your ViewModel. And use `@Html.Raw` to display it in the view.

Greetings

Comment: Thanks eixmenis for your answer. Another question is: this approach leads to a security issue. How can I authenticate the request from my application to another application?

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the delay! Didn't saw your comment.
Ajax calls will include cookies (for the specified domain), so if you have auth cookie for the other app and use the ajax call it will work.

If not, you'll need to use some custom auth mechanism (use some token or http headers) to authenticate the ajax call and/or retrieve the auth cookie for the other webapp.